# Eliminating Interferential Curve of Text in Images？

Tags: image-processing, ocr

[image]

As you can see,I have an image of some formulas

but it has some interferential curve,so how can I to remove it?

I tried to erode and dilate but failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those lines by using image inpainting. But need to make a mask first. Take a look at this- 
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

I just tried one see-
[image: Made a rough mask]

This code (python) helps you make a mask:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
imgg=cv2.imread("your_image.png")
flag = False
def draw(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global flag

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        flag = True

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if flag == True:
                cv2.circle(img,(x,y),2,(255,255,255),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        flag = False

img = np.zeros(imgg.shape[:2], np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',imgg)
    cv2.imshow("mask",img)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1))==27:
        break
cv2.imwrite("mask.png",img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I read the link and find that I need to have the mask.But now the difficulty for me is to find the mask,if I have mask,I don't need to use inpainting,I just set it to the back ground or just set to the digit's color

Comment: if you are saying you'll make the mask values equivalent to that of the neighbouring pixels in your image, that's pretty much what inpainting does.
Also you cant find mask..you need to make one according to your interferences. Most other methods like erosion etc will have impact your fomulas too and degrade the image more