# How to correct a line dropout in an image in python?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing

I have an image having line dropout,how to identify the position of the black line and correct it.

[image: img]

Comment: Is there any original that could be used to differ? Do you have any script?

Comment: So what are you looking for? How can you identify where that is happening if there is no code?

Comment: No,I don't have any other image,i have read that thresholding can be used to correct it but i don't know how thresholding will give the position of black line in the image.

Comment: And say you are able to detect the dropout, then how would you like to fix it?

Comment: When the line containing sum of pixels zero or near to zero will be identified(i.e. the black line),it will be replaced by the average of the sum of  pixel value just below that line and just above that line.

Comment: Check about image inpainting [here.](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html). Also what are you working on ? matlab or opencv?

Comment: I am working on opencv.

Comment: check out this answer [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688099/eliminating-interferential-curve-of-text-in-images/45688308#45688308)
 Just draw along the line with your mouse.

Comment: I have read about line dropout from the following link ,and I have to correct it as mentioned in it .This is the link http://www.csre.iitb.ac.in/~avikb/GNR401/DIP/DIP_401_lecture_1.pdf